# How does one find how many nilpotent groups are of any particular order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For example, a past exam question asks to find all the nilpotent groups of order 70. How many are there and is there a general method to finding the answer?

Comment: In general, this is practically impossible. For exam questions, one should use that such a group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, which makes it easy as long as the prime powers dividing the order are small.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't know how to find the number of non-isomorphic nilpotent groups out of that information, will you please explain some more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can use the fact that a nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow-$p$ subgroups.  For a group $G$ of order 70, we have $70 = 2\cdot 5\cdot7$.  This means that $G \cong H\times K \times L$, where $|H|=2$, $|K| = 5$, and $|L|=7$.  Since $|H|$ is prime, that means $H$ is isomorphic to $C_2$, the cyclic group of order 2.  Similarly, $K\cong C_5$ and $L\cong C_7$.  This means that $G$ must be  isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_5 \times C_7$.  In other words, up to isomorphism, there is only one nilpotent group of order $70$, and that group is $C_2 \times C_5 \times C_7$.

Comment: Thank you. And if for example we end up with powers of prime numbers?

Comment: @Maria For Sylow-$p$ subgroups with prime power order, the situation becomes more difficult because you need to classify all groups of order $p^n$.  There are ways to attack this more general problem but things definitely are more complicated.  Please accept this answer if it helps!

Comment: Yes, I will accept. Can you please clarify how does your answer answer the question of the number of nilpotent groups of order 70? I don't follow exactly.

Comment: @Maria I edited the answer.  In general, when questions ask 'How many groups ...', they mean up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The paper 'Nilpotent Numbers' of Pakianathan and Shankar (http://www2.math.ou.edu/~shankar/papers/nil2.pdf), shows that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent if and only if $p^k\not\equiv 1$ mod $q$, whenever $p,q$ are distinct primes with $p^k$ and $q$ dividing $n$.